# Remove first character from string

Tags: swift, barcode, linea-pro

I have this code:

```
func barcodeData(_ barcode: String!, type: Int32) {
    referenceField.text = barcode!
}
```

When I scan a barcode the textfield is replaced by it. It's always an "R" in the beginning of the barcode followed by some digits.

I want the textfield to display only the numbers. So if the barcode scanned is "R454512" I want the textfield to show only "454512"

Could someone explain this to me? I'm pretty new in this barcode-world.
I don't have any values yet so how am I supposed to use this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by **I don't have any values yet** don't you get `R454512` value in `barcode` argument.

Comment: I have the function that uses a external device to scan a barcode. But I don't know the barcode until it's scanned? So how am I supposed to type let text = "R454512"? If there are other values too?

Comment: @moseby Write like this `referenceField.text = String(barcode.characters.dropFirst())`

Comment: Thank you very much @NiravD

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is with a characterSet. This way if there are more letters or spaces at the start or end of the string, you will get the correct result:

```
barcode.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
```